# Make Thumbnail from video

Tags: command-line, thumbnails

How can I make a simple capture from a video. Preferably from the command line?

Idea: take 9 snapshots for 9 even placed (on the timeline) times, and save them as JPGs

Example:

```
Movie length = 10 min
T1= snapshot of 1 min
T2= snapshot of 2 min
......
T9= snapshot of 9 min
   |   |
 T1| T2| T3
---+---+---
 T4| T5| T6
---+---+---
 T7| T8| T9
   |   |
```

What's the best program to do this?
Are there any opensource programs?

Answer (score 6):

[ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is an excellent open source tool for manipulating videos, including extracting frames.

To extract single frame from specific timestamp you can use command like

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -r 1  -t 00:01:00 -f image2 image%05d.png
```

-r is framerate. You can also use command like

```
ffmpeg -i video.avi -r 1/1440 -f image2 image%05d.png
```

to get one frame every one minute (assuming 24FPS video). The %05d means that ordinal number of each thumbnail image should be formatted using 5 digits.

If you want to combine images as montage (your grid), you can use imagemagick after extracting frames using ffmpeg.

Comment: `[image2 @ 0x55d71a98fa80] Could not get frame filename number 2 from pattern '....png'. Use '-frames:v 1' for a single image, or '-update' option, or use a pattern such as %03d within the filename.
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument

> ffm -i "$videoFile" -frames:v 1 -f image2 "regularSingleFile.png";`

Answer (score 2):

It's not a command line program, but you may also use [qframecatcher](http://developer.berlios.de/projects/qframecatcher/).

For ubuntu/debian the requirements are:
    sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev libxine-dev build-essential

```
wget http://download.berlios.de/qframecatcher/qframecatcher-0.4.1.tar.gz
tar xzf qframecatcher-0.4.1.tar.gz
cd qframecatcher/src
qmake
make
./qframecatcher
```

Source: http://blog.radevic.com/2008/06/how-to-create-movie-or-video-frame.html

Answer (score 1):

[vcsi](https://github.com/amietn/vcsi) is a command-line tool written in Python that can be used to create a 3 by 3 grid of snapshots with the following command:

```
vcsi -g 3x3 video.mkv -o output.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

My use-case is just one thumbnail from a video, just a single file to use as a `<video>` tag poster. So, what would be a fast way to make this?

With `ffmpeg`, you can do this:

```
ffmpeg -ss 123 -y -i video.mp4 -r 1 -updatefirst 1 -frames 1 poster.jpg
```

That will give you the frame near second `123` of the `video.mp4` saved as `poster.jpg`.

The problem, as you can see, is that we need to know which second is right.

In order to keep our dependencies low, we'll use ffmpeg itself for this:

```
# Get the time as h:m:s (non-padded)
l=$(ffmpeg -i video.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration: | sed -r 's/\..*//;s/.*: //;s/0([0-9])/\1/g')
# Convert that into seconds
s=$((($(cut -f1 -d: <<< $l) * 60 + $(cut -f2 -d: <<< $l)) * 60 + $(cut -f3 -d: <<< $l)))
# Get frame at 25% as the thumbnail
ffmpeg -ss $((s / 4)) -y -i video.mp4 -r 1 -updatefirst 1 -frames 1 poster.jpg
```

25% of the video seems like a common choice, but you can make it 33% or 50% too.

[Here's a script that does this](https://github.com/CamiloMM/shell-scripts#thumbsh).

Comment: `Error splitting the argument list: Option not found`